# What the UI thread will do if Activity/UI is idle for some(may be long) time

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I think title itself says what the my question is...

AFAIK, in Java, when work of a Thread is completed i.e. `run()` method has completed executing, Thread itself will finish and dies.

So, When my Activity(I mean UI) is idle for a long time, what the UI thread will do? does it sleeps? or does it do any other work?

Thanks to all...

Comment: Simple `Nothing` , or may be your screen saver will take place.

Comment: @Kedarnath how can you keep a thread alive without anywork to it? Java has deprecated `resume()` and `suspend()` methods... and what do you mean by screensaver here?

Comment: a simple while(true){} loop will keep your thread live forever but then it may cause ANR in android.

Comment: @Kedarnath please read my question properly. even `while(true)` is also a work for thread. so do you mean UI thread just sits on `while(true)` condition when it is idle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the question is not really about Java threads in general, but about the Android "main thread" (also called the "UI thread").

To quote from the JavaDoc for the Android [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> When a process is created for your application, its main thread is
>   dedicated to running a message queue that takes care of managing the
>   top-level application objects (activities, broadcast receivers, etc)
>   and any windows they create. You can create your own threads, and
>   communicate back with the main application thread through a Handler.
>   This is done by calling the same post or sendMessage methods as
>   before, but from your new thread. The given Runnable or Message will
>   then be scheduled in the Handler's message queue and processed when
>   appropriate.

In other words: The main thread is responsible for dequeuing messages/runnables from a queue and processing them. That main thread is blocked while the queue is empty (since there is nothing for it to do). If you use a Handler *that was created in the main thread*, that Handler's messages and runnables will actually be added to the same queue used by the main thread. Normally, the main thread will run as long as the process does.

*Note: An Android app can actually have multiple processes, and each one will have its own main thread. However, most Android apps will only have one process (and therefore one main thread).*

Comment: A good answer... can you please elaborate the sentence `"main thread is blocked while the queue is empty"`... how it is blocked? does it goes to sleep? or just sits on `while(true)` conditions as kedarnath said?

Comment: See the implementation of android.os.Looper.loop(), at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/Looper.java#Looper.loop%28%29. Notice the "// might block" comment on the call to queue.next().  The queue is actually an android.os.MessageQueue, and you can look at its implementation as well if you want even more details.

Comment: @RuntimeException Blocking on the message queue is implemented using `poll()` system call with native code. It's not a busy loop like `while(true)`.

Comment: @cybersam Thanks... I observed an infinite `for` loop in `Looper.loop()` which keeps the thread busy...